# Adding custom filter in spring security

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to make a custom AuthenticationProcessingFilter to save some user data in the session after successful login

here's my filter:

```
package projects.internal;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter;

public class MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends AuthenticationProcessingFilter {


 protected void onSuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult)
   throws IOException {
  super.onSuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, authResult);
  request.getSession().setAttribute("myValue", "My value is set");
 }
}
```

and here's my security.xml file

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"  
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

 <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">

 </global-method-security>
 <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
  <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" filters="none" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/scripts/**" filters="none" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/styles/**" filters="none" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/p/login.jsp" filters="none" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/p/register" filters="none" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/p/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

     <form-login
   login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
   login-page="/p/login.jsp"   
   authentication-failure-url="/p/login_error.jsp" />
  <logout />
 </http>

 <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
 <authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
  </authentication-provider>
 </authentication-manager>

 <beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="projects.internal.MyAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
 <custom-filter position="AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
    </beans:bean>


 </beans:beans>
```

it gives an error here:

```
<custom-filter position="AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER" />
```

> multiple annotation found at this line:cvc-attribute.3
>   cvc-complex-type.4
>   cvc-enumeration-vaild

what is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the name 'authenticationProcessingFilter' isn't already taken by the default Spring Security bean?

Comment: There is a better tool for what you need:`authentication-success-handler` - add this to your `<form>`, I think it's fits better than filter.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe that's a valid filter position in Spring Security 3.0 schema.  Check out [Security Namespace Configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-custom-filters).  I don't see it listed anymore.  Perhaps try `BASIC_AUTH_FILTER`

Answer (score 2):

- `AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER` is not a valid filter alias, you should use `FORM_LOGIN_FILTER`.
- `<custom-filter>` should be put inside `<http>`